# Managing and plotting data over dateline

Tags: python, numpy

I know this question has been asked before, however focuses on Cartopy.

My current work is looking at a phenomenon over the dateline, and will be working on a box in the pacific ocean that crosses the dateline. Managing and plotting this data has been a challenge as values go from 179 to -179 over one index.

I can subset my latitudes easily with

```
lat_mask=[(lat<=20)&(lat>=-20)]  #Tropics +-20* only
lat_masked=lat[lat_mask]
```

Which works fine.

```
lon=np.add(lon,180)  #Reset longitudes to 0-360 from -180 to 180
lon_mask=[(lon>=110)&(lon<=300)]
```

also works fine... BUT for the exact **opposite** region i'm looking at.
But the region I do want:

```
lon_mask=[(lon<=110)|(lon>=300)]
```

**does not work.**
I can do them separately and make graphs for each region East and West of the dateline but I want them combined as one dataset/graph. So that I have a mask for [300-360 0-110] which I can plot as a single image.

I'm looking for a smart way of storing the information for usability and plotability.

I've been trying to work out how to reindex it all but it's making my head hurt. I am looking for a **robust** solution as it will be used regularly. I originally thought this was a matplotlib issue but i think it is the way my data is being stored.

**EDIT:** Changed & to | - but now have this resulting problem.

I Feel like

```
lon= np.roll(lon,len(lon)/2)
```

or something might help to effectively move the dateline to somewhere else but I can't quite work it out.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used XArray:

```
    dataset= dataset.assign_coords(lon=(dataset.lon % 360)).roll(lon=(dataset.dims['lon'] // 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

`lon_mask=[(lon<=110)|(lon>=300)]` is what you want. The longitude is *either* less than 110 *or* bigger than 300. Surely no number can be less than 110 *and* bigger than 300 at the same time.

Comment: Ah good one! Slipped me. Changed to | rather than & but have the resulting problem seen in the image. Back to front! I need 300-360, 0-110 somehow.

Comment: Just add two more condition checks: `((lon>=0)&(lon<=110))|((lon>=300)&(lon<=360)`

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't do anything. I need the indexes to go from [300:360, 0:110]